# Removing <br /> immediately before list

Tags: php, html

I have code that iterates through a database using PHP, and processes the HTML to look like this:

```
First line etc<br />
Text blah blah blah blah, etc<br />
Moar text blah blah blah,<br />
<ul>
    <li>List Item 1</li>
    <li>List Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

However, I want the `<br />` immediately before the `<ul>` removed. i.e.

```
...
Moar text blah blah blah,
<ul>
...
```

I cannot use CSS to correct this problem, as it is being parsed into a PDF format.

How do I go about removing the `<br />` immediately before a `<ul>` (or `<ol>`)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be very helpful if you show your PHP code

Comment: `echo $string . ($i == ($count - 1) ? '' : '<br />');`
where your loop condition is `$i < $count` else if it is `$i <= $count` {`echo $string . ($i == $count ? '' : '<br />');`}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions like this :

```
<?php

$text = 'First line etc<br />
Text blah blah blah blah, etc<br />
Moar text blah blah blah,<br />
<ul>
    <li>List Item 1</li>
    <li>List Item 2</li>
</ul>
';

$text = preg_replace('#<br\s*/>\s*<ul>#ims',"\n<ul>",$text);
```

Comment: That's perfect! Exactly what I wanted. I'm not very familiar with regular expressions, and I don't have the time to learn them at the moment.

Comment: See the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0):

I use arrays for this.

```
$foo = get_elements_to_output_in_some_way_or_another();

echo implode("<br />\n", $foo);
```